External Load Balancer Path rule is not working with Cloud Run Function
I am trying to achieve something simple yet I can't figure out why it isn't working.
I have two Cloud Run function that are deployed independent from each other as two cloud run services. I want to access them from an external Load Balancer so that:
-example.com takes me to the 1st function,
-example.com/api takes me to the 2nd function
For above to happen I have written the following path rule in the Advanced host and path rule part of Load Balancer
defaultService: projects/example-proj/global/backendServices/fun1
name: matcher1
routeRules:
- matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /api/*
  priority: 1
  routeAction:
    weightedBackendServices:
    - backendService: projects/example-proj/global/backendServices/fun2
      weight: 100

With this setup I am able to access 1st function by going to example.com, but going to example.com/api gives me 404 error.

To solve this, you need to remove the wildcard mask “/*” from your prefixMatch. Your code should look like this:
defaultService: projects/example-proj/global/backendServices/fun1
name: matcher1
routeRules:
- matchRules:
  - prefixMatch: /api   #Just remove “/*” on this line.
  priority: 1
  routeAction:
    weightedBackendServices:
    - backendService: projects/example-proj/global/backendServices/fun2
      weight: 100

Your provided prefixMatch /api/* attempts to match any directory or file within the /api path. If the path or file does not exist, you will likely receive an error message.
